# redirect from one controller to another

Tags: codeigniter

My Codeigniter route.php is set to :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome/view';
```

I am trying to redirect to  a test controller from the default controller's  view method using redirect('test') but I am getting a Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CI_Exceptions::show_exception() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given .

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function view()
    {
        redirect('test');
    }
}
```

-

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'hi';
    }   
}
```

I am expecting hi as the output as I am redirecting to the test controller . I am not sure what the error actually means . Could somebody please tell me what does the error mean and what is going wrong ?

Comment: What happens when you browse to `test`, e.g. `https://example.com/test`  or if you don't have an .htaccess in place `https://example.com/index.php/test` ?

Comment: You do have those two controllers in separate files - right?  Your post implies they are in the same one so I want to make sure.

Comment: @DFriend you always ask the right questions bro, and never jump to the answer without knowing the problem like MANY others.

Comment: If I go to  https://example.com/test I am seeing the correct output . The controller is working fine . The redirect is not working though . Yes , both controllers are in different files .

Comment: What is the value you have set for `$config['base_url']` in `application/config/config.php`?

Comment: $config['base_url'] = ' ';

Comment: Just found out redirect() needs the helper 'url'  .. 
 https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?fbclid=IwAR16bGJ32j87Kos5nVnaiy8PJquSFkH1wefmIPKVqgVdfuwyWF8COu-5Ro8#loading-this-helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any of the functions in CodeIgniter's [URL Helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) (e.g. `redirect()`, `base_url()`, etc. ) to work the configuration item `$config['base_url']` must be set.

The notes with this setting in `/application/config/config.php` says

```
/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Base Site URL
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
  | WITH a trailing slash:
  |
  | http://example.com/
  |
  | WARNING: You MUST set this value!
  |
  | If it is not set, then CodeIgniter will try guess the protocol and path
  | your installation, but due to security concerns the hostname will be set
  | to $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] if available, or localhost otherwise.
  | The auto-detection mechanism exists only for convenience during
  | development and MUST NOT be used in production!
  |
  | If you need to allow multiple domains, remember that this file is still
  | a PHP script and you can easily do that on your own.
  |
 */
```

Pay particular attention to the line

> **WARNING: You MUST set this value!**

and don't forget the trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
redirect(base_url('Test/index'));
```

Answer (score 0):

define route for test controller also in your config/routes.php file.

```
$route['test']='Test/index';
```

And redirect this url.

```
 redirect(base_url('test'), 'refresh');
```